# How do I spawn particles inside a designated area?

Tags: particles

I am trying to use an emitter to get particles to spawn and stay inside a specific area (in this case, a cube) but all I've been able to achieve is for the particles to spawn on the outside of the cube and not on the inside. I'm not sure how to achieve this or if an emitter is even the appropriate modifier to use. [image: particles don't spawn inside cube]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try choosing volume under source->emit from...

[image]